# rmiexception while starting glassfish server

Tags: glassfish, rmi

I have the glassfish server and I am trying to run the server from netbeans. I am getting the following errors:

```
WARNING:   Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system, Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, AcceptAll = false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = false} due to exception java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
SEVERE:   java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net:8686/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:826)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:431)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:333)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:249)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:641)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:426)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:157)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 13 more
```

Now after searching google I came across various suggestions.

a. Checking the firewall. The firewall is not an issue. Because this was working fine just two days ago and it stopped suddenly.

b. Setting the JMX port from the admin console. I did it and it didn't work.

c. Checking the port to see whether it is already used. I checked it. Moreover, I restarted the glassfish server. Even restarted the computer. Nothing changed.

Now I need the help of some wise guys to give some clue in resolving this.

Thanks

Comment: Uh the problem seemed to have solved by setting the IP to 127.0.0.1 from 0.0.0.0. This raises the next question. How did it work previously?

Answer (score 11):

start up the domain, get into the admin console.

In the admin console, navigate 
Configurations > server-config > AdminService

There is a tab in the main window that is titled "Edit JMX Connector"

The IP address is probably set to "0.0.0.0" (all IP's)

change that to "127.0.0.1"

you MIGHT also need to add an entry in your hosts file 
for the domain name in the errror 
"mymachine.SOMEDomain.net" or whatever.. so that it resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is

```
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: MAZUMDAM4.americas.hpqcorp.net; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

during rebind(). See the stack trace. RMI is getting no response at all from that host when attempting to bind a remote object to its Registry. This is a network topology problem or possibly a DNS problem. It should be trying to bind to a registry at 'localhost' only.